# apache restart error Segmentation fault: 11 $HTTPD "$@"

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, apache2

I'm new to web development and wanted to create my own local server on mac os Sierra in order to do some development. I've followed a (few) tutorials on getting apache , php and mysql up and running, and have only made it to the php part ,which is where I am failing at the moment.

I managed to access localhost via http://localhost/~username and found my directory there, however once I uncomment the php LoadModule in the httpd.conf my ability to access localhost fails and I am thrown with the error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. This is  after I tried to restart apache using

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Which threw this error:

> httpd not running, trying to start
>   /usr/sbin/apachectl: line 92: 11399 Segmentation fault: 11  $HTTPD "$@"

The error logs from `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log`, had the following to say:

> AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
>   AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
>   [Mon May 01 19:33:52.138346 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3454] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) PHP/7.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Mon May 01 19:33:52.138434 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3454] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
>   [Mon May 01 19:37:22.694456 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3454] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>   AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
>   AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
>   [Mon May 01 19:53:54.632167 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4059] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) PHP/7.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Mon May 01 19:53:54.632251 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4059] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
>   [Mon May 01 20:04:26.379765 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4059] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

I've spent several hours looking at similar topics on stackoverflow as well as other sources but to no avail. I am fairly new to all of this as well and thus I'm not overly clued up on a lot of the terminology. From my understanding (whatever little it may be), it may be something to do with a bad module or php7 not linking up properly ?

I am using apache version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug  8 2016 16:31:34
php version 7.1.1
```

and configtest gives me the following:

> AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
>   AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
>   Syntax OK

Any advice would greatly be appreciated. Completely gassed out on what to do next :(

Comment: Have you tried reading the error messages? It's in English fyi. `/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com` directory does not exist. So create it manually first an see what happens. It's not rocket science. Programming is all about **reading** what is happening and fix it.

Comment: perhaps better to ask on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I've read them all but as I said, I've been following tutorials because I'm new to this. None of which mentioned creating those directories so i didn't.  What would the purpose of those directories serve @xorifelse

Comment: Thanks @nogad . I certainly will add this post there as well

Comment: That would be (according to the error messages) your **document root**. The root folder of your webserver. `localhost` would reffer to `/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com/index.html`

Comment: You can also look at your apache config to change that directory. Mine is `/var/www` in your example it could be `/var/www/site1` or `/var/www/site2`

Comment: And @nogad is correct, this is not a programming question. Read [ask] to see what topics are allowed here. Research is mandatory and following a guide that fails without an attempt to resolve is a no no.

Comment: A missing document root folder wouldn't trigger a segfault, it's just a warning. Apache would still start and show a 403 when trying to access the root. As suggested in the answer, I would really consider running a pre-packaged setup like XAMPP or WAMP, unless you really want to use the default OSX stack and hack something together.

Answer (score 25):

The "Segmentation fault" error when starting Apache occurs because Apache tries to load both the old and the new version of php at the same time. Looking at these instructions: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/ , the installation script creates a file that loads the new php 7 version in

```
/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf
```

The script is also *supposed* to disable the loading of the old php version by, in the apache configuration file,

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

commenting out this line:

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

but it didn't do that for me. As soon as I commented it out manually, Apache started again using

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Comment: Had the same problem after upgrading php 5.6 to 7. Thanks

Comment: That saved my hide. I blew somewhere around 3 hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: On OSX with Apache installed through Homebrew, the actual config is in `/usr/local/etc/httpd`instead of `/etc/apache2` so I had to change it there. Otherwise works nicely, thanks

Comment: Thanks for this, saved me almost having to give up and reboot my machine.

Comment: This helped me a ton. Was getting random ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in my browser, checked logs and saw seg fault, which led me here. Had to comment out this line in my `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file: `LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`. Appeared it was already being loaded somewhere else, which gave me only a warning when I did `apachectl configtest`

Comment: Incredibly helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create the virtual host on your localhost you should be change the httpd-vhosts.conf , hosts file and httpd.conf for Enable Virtual Host ....

BUT

if only you want to install XAMPP or WAMP , you don't need to change the files , create new folder in htdocs folder(XAMPP) or www folder(WAMP) and type in the addressbar like this :
localhost/newfolder

**reinstall XAMPP and create new folder project in *htdocs* folder.**

- Directory htdocs folder : /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/(create project folder)
- Enable Apache and Mysql
- and type in addressbar firefox or chrome :localhost/projectfoldername

please read this post : 
https://donatstudios.com/PHP-in-OS-X-Yosemite

Download Xampp : https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: While I do not have any OSX experience I dont see how this would resolve the question.